# Count function in a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, count, distinct-values

I have the following query that counts members:

```
`SELECT 
distinct count(cst_recno) AS [Member ID],
adr_country AS Country
FROM 
mb_membership
JOIN mb_member_type on mbt_key = mbr_mbt_key
JOIN co_customer ON cst_key=mbr_cst_key and mbr_delete_flag =0 and 
cst_delete_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_individual ON cst_key=ind_cst_key and ind_delete_flag=0
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_customer ON cxc_cst_key_1 = co_customer.cst_key and 
(cxc_end_date is null or datediff(dd,getdate(),cxc_end_date) >=0) and 
cxc_rlt_code='Chapter Member' 
LEFT JOIN co_chapter ON cxc_cst_key_2=chp_cst_key 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key=cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key=cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN co_country on adr_country=cty_code
LEFT JOIN co_region on rgn_key=cty_rgn_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_key=mem_cst_key 
WHERE mbr_join_date >= '7/1/2015' and mbt_code not like '%Council%'
AND ind_int_code <> 'staff' and cst_org_name_dn not like '%urban land ins%' 
and cst_eml_address_dn not like '%@uli.org'
and adr_country ='singapore'
group by adr_country`
```

and the query returns:

```
Member ID   Country
145         Singapore
```

However, I know that it includes a few duplicates because when I take out a count function and don't have a group by clause it returns 140 distinct rows.
When I check why it includes a few dupes it is caused by one of the dates.
Can you advise? I basically want to run the query that will display 140 distinct count of Member ID:

```
Member ID   Country
140         Singapore
```

Comment: don't you need a `count(distinct cst_recno)`?

Comment: You sure you need all those left join to get the count

Comment: I just kept my initial query, but no I do not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `SELECT distinct count(cst_recno)...` use `SELECT count(distinct cst_recno)...`:

```
SELECT 
count(distinct cst_recno) AS [Member ID],
adr_country AS Country
FROM 
mb_membership
JOIN mb_member_type on mbt_key = mbr_mbt_key
JOIN co_customer ON cst_key=mbr_cst_key and mbr_delete_flag =0 and 
cst_delete_flag=0 
LEFT JOIN co_individual ON cst_key=ind_cst_key and ind_delete_flag=0
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_customer ON cxc_cst_key_1 = co_customer.cst_key and 
(cxc_end_date is null or datediff(dd,getdate(),cxc_end_date) >=0) and 
cxc_rlt_code='Chapter Member' 
LEFT JOIN co_chapter ON cxc_cst_key_2=chp_cst_key 
LEFT JOIN co_customer_x_address ON cst_cxa_key=cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN co_address ON adr_key=cxa_adr_key 
LEFT JOIN co_country on adr_country=cty_code
LEFT JOIN co_region on rgn_key=cty_rgn_key 
LEFT JOIN vw_client_uli_member_type  WITH (NOLOCK)  ON cst_key=mem_cst_key 
WHERE mbr_join_date >= '7/1/2015' and mbt_code not like '%Council%'
AND ind_int_code <> 'staff' and cst_org_name_dn not like '%urban land ins%' 
and cst_eml_address_dn not like '%@uli.org'
and adr_country ='singapore'
group by adr_country`
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)